# Filter syslog messages

Tags: cpanel, centos7, syslog, suexec

On Syslog, how can I filter all messages from "suexec"?

My syslog has zillions of messages like this:

```
Nov 24 09:44:40 juno suexec[20253]: uid: (1020/cetn) gid: (1020/cetn) cmd: ea-php56
Nov 24 09:44:49 juno suexec[20271]: uid: (1020/cetn) gid: (1020/cetn) cmd: ea-php56
Nov 24 09:44:56 juno suexec[20284]: uid: (1020/cetn) gid: (1020/cetn) cmd: ea-php56
Nov 24 09:45:07 juno suexec[20785]: uid: (1020/cetn) gid: (1020/cetn) cmd: ea-php56
```

It's a cPanel server on CentOS 7.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

These could be considered as a good read:

https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/system_administrators_guide/ch-web_servers

https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html-single/system_administrators_guide/index

I think you might need to create a filter specifically for rsyslog in order to save the suexec messages to a file instead of being displayed to syslog